# How to Prevent Tkinter from waiting for any action

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have some requirement regarding Tkinter module. Down is the example code what is causing me issue

```
    import Tkinter
    from Tkconstants import *
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    frame = Tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    label = Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Hello, user- have a look at your data")
    label.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    tk.mainloop()
```

This is a small piece inside a program where I've to check for some data and then create excelsheet with the result on hourly basis. For information purpose I'm displaying this data using Tkinter (new to kinter). After display of data the program has to sleep for an hour and then resume from beginning (start collecting information, write to same excelsheet and disply to screen).
Now the issue is that after creating a widget interpreter waits there for further input. Anyways this is the default behaviour, but I don't want it to happen. 
Is there any way that would release the execution from Tkinter main loop & continue execution.
OR if you could suggest for any other kind of window to be created to avoid this waiting.

Thanks alot.
Kriss332

Answer (score 0):

You need for tkinter to "wait for input" because that is how the program responds to events, such as requests to redraw, to quit, to resize, etc.

If you want to wait an hour and then refresh the display, there is a command to do that.

Break your code into two pieces: one that creates the main window, and one that fills the window with information from the spreadsheet. Then use `tk.after` to run the "refresh" function again in the hour.